# How do I get the decimal precision of a floating point number?

Tags: swift, floating-point, precision

How do I get the decimal  precision of a floating point number in Swift? All the existing answers use some form of string conversion, which is inefficient. I'm specifically looking for a method that does not involve string conversion.

---

This question was based on a misconception. I have realized and corrected my mistake in understanding, thanks to @MartinR and @SimonByrne.

Comment: Can you precise (pun intended :) what you mean by the precision of a floating point number? From your answer I assume that you are talking about *decimal* precision. But Float and Double use a binary representation, which means that a number like 0.123 *cannot* be represented exactly, it would be more like 0.12299999999999999822.

Comment: Note that your proposed solution gives the result `15` for `getPrecision(0.123 + 3.456)`, which *might* be unexpected.

Comment: Don't get me wrong: Both your question and the answer might be useful, but you should define exactly what you are computing.

Comment: @MartinR: I've fixed my answer. `getPrecision(0.123 + 3.456)` now outputs `3`

Comment: As @MartinR said you are getting the _binary precision_. By the way, you are doing a lot of floating point operations. I suppose the float to string conversions a really optimised, afterwards counting characters is cheaper. If you really need exact decimal precision, you might consider if using `NSDecimalNumber` class fits your needs.

Comment: You should consider `Float`s and similars only as _continuous_ values. If you need decimal values then that is not the right type to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other commenters have pointed out, there isn't really any such thing as "decimal precision" of a floating point number: when you write something like `x = 0.123`, you are really setting `x` to be the closest double-precision floating point number to 0.123, which is in fact:

0.1229999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875

Based on your proposed answer, your question would be more precisely stated as computing the minimum number of decimal places in a decimal *approximation* to the floating point number.

For this your code should be correct for "reasonable" values, though if you have more than 22 decimal places you might see some errors, as the `tens` variable will no longer be exact (10<sup>23</sup> cannot be exactly represent by a double precision float). For more details on this you should read up on binary to decimal conversion: I recommend taking a look at Rick Regan's webpage:
http://www.exploringbinary.com/tag/convert-to-decimal/

Answer (score 0):

<s>This is how to do it:</s>

```
func getPrecision(valueFunction: (@autoclosure () -> Double)) -> Int
{
    let value = valueFunction()
    var tens: Double = 1.0
    var precision: Int = 0

    while (floor((value * tens) + 0.1) / tens) != value
    {
        tens *= 10
        precision++
    }

    return precision
}
```

**Edit:** This answer is wrong, as correctly pointed out by Simon Byrne.

Comment: See my other answer: you can also simplify the check slightly by simply checking if  `value*tens` is integer valued.